# How to Display 4 Records in a row from the database

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display my products from the database. I'm trying to split it using the if 4%=0, but I can't get it to display 4 items in a row.
please tell me how can i do this or please provide me any other example..

thanks in advance

Her is my code

```
    <?php

/**************MYSQL Connection*************************/
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("dogs_db", $con);
/**************MYSQL Connection ENDS*************************/

    $split = 0;
    $display_all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dogsinfo");
    ?>
    <table>
  <tr>
  <?php
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($display_all)) {
$id = $fetch['id'];
$dogname = $fetch['dogname'];
?>
<tr>
    <td><label><?php echo $i; ?></label></td>
    <td><label><a href="details.php?id=
<?php echo $fetch["id"];?>&tablename=<?php echo "dogsinfo"; ?>">
<img src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $fetch["file_name"]; ?>" alt="
<?php echo  $fetch["file_name"]; ?>" 
 title="<?php echo $fetch["file_name"]; ?>"  height="100" width="100" />
 </a></label></td>
<tr>
 <td>DogName:</td>                          
    <td><label><?php echo $fetch["dogname"];?>           </label>     
 </td>
</tr>
</tr>
  <?php 
    $split++;   
if ($split%4==0){
    echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please Reply.......

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `dogsinfo` LIMIT  4
```

This will display the first 4 records from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProductCatId = 1 ORDER BY `ProductCatId` ASC LIMIT 0 , 4";
```

in which you can put desire no of record with position..

Like if you want to see record of 5,6,7,8 then just simply use

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProductCatId = 1 ORDER BY `ProductCatId` ASC LIMIT 4 , 4";
```

first no is position..and second no is how many no you want.. hope this helps.. :)

edit 1: sorry I use example.. you can change variable name..:)

Edit 2: please have idea by my this code

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProductCatId = 1 ORDER BY `ProductCatId` ASC LIMIT 0 , 4";
$Result  = mysql_query($sql);

// $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProductCatId = 1 ORDER BY `ProductCatId` ASC LIMIT 4 , 4";
//    $Result  = mysql_query($sql);

// $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProductCatId = 1 ORDER BY `ProductCatId` ASC LIMIT 8 , 4";
//    $Result  = mysql_query($sql);

// $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProductCatId = 1 ORDER BY `ProductCatId` ASC LIMIT 12 , 4";
//    $Result  = mysql_query($sql);

// $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProductCatId = 1 ORDER BY `ProductCatId` ASC LIMIT 16 , 4";
//    $Result  = mysql_query($sql);

?>
<div class="PageContent">
<?php while($list = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
{ ?>
    <div class="">
      <?php { ?>
        <div class="InnerDiv"><?php  echo $list['ProductName'];?>
           <div class="ImageDiv">
             <center>
                <img src="<?php echo CAT_IMAGE_URL.$list['ProductImage'];?>" width="120px" height="180"/>
             </center>
           </div>
           <center>
            <div class="a2">Price</div>
           </center>
        </div>
      <?php }?>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
```

and here is a noob idea(sorry for that) that you can run 5 SQL queries and then show them as per your need and your order..

Comment: I want to display the total records in below fashion................. image-1    image-2    image3    image-4  ..... like this ... consider i am having 20 records in my database then it should be displayed in 5 rows 4 records in each row..............

Comment: Hey pavan m wrking to solve your qus bt till then you can get this idea of mine..sorry as its not good bt it will help and you can use list1 list2 list3 and so on..hope i help..and believe me m wrking hard on this too..:)